# Swift closures supplied to an async call dont take any arguments nor return any arguments

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, closures

In CS193P Stanford lectures on iTunesU lecturer mentions in lecture 8 at 30:14  re multithreading that the closure you supply to an async call "takes no arguments and returns no arguments". That surprises me because a little while later he gives an example of an iOS method (37:01) where the closure is able to return arguments i.e.:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response, error ) in  ...
```

Also there are many other iOS methods that seem to return arguments to their completion closures. Am I missing something here? Why can't the closures supplied with an async call return arguments in a similar way to the dataTask call above.

Comment: by "an async call" he most likely meant "a call to `DispatchQueue.async`," not "a call to any asynchronous method."

Comment: @NobodyNada ... yes you are correct ... he is referring to DispatchQueue.async ... so do i take it that any closure provided to a DispatchQueue.async call is not able to have any return arguments like the data and response and error arguments that are "returned" in the supplied closure by the session.dataTask call. Or am i simply misinterpreting what is meant that a closure "returns" no arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataTask(with:)` is not the same thing as `DispatchQueue`'s `async`.

First of all, remember that you're using a [trailing closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).  When the last argument to a function is a closure (i.e. a "block" of code), the closure may be placed outside of the parentheses. The following code, which uses the trailing closure syntax:

```
someQueue.async {
    //do something
}
```

is equivalent to the following code, which does not use the trailing closure syntax.:

```
someQueue.async(execute: {
    //do something
})
```

Also, keep in mind that closures do not "return" parameters, they *accept* parameters.  The parameters are the input to the closure, while the return value is the output from the closure.

---

[The function signature for `DispatchQueue`'s `async` is:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300100-asyncafter)

```
func async(
    group: DispatchGroup? = default, 
    qos: DispatchQoS = default, 
    flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags = default, 
    execute work: @escaping () -> Void
)
```

`group`, `qos`, and `flags` have default values, so they can be ignored here.  The important part is the `execute` parameter, whose type is `@escaping () -> Void`.  That means "a closure which takes no arguments and returns `Void` (i.e. no value)."

---

[The function signature for `URLSession's` `dataTask` method is:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask)

```
func dataTask(
    with request: URLRequest, 
    completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void
) -> URLSessionDataTask
```

`completionHandler` is of type `@escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void`, which means it accepts three parameters (an optional `Data`, an optional `URLResponse`, and an optional `Error`) and returns `Void`.

---

Both functions accept closures as parameters, but they accept closures with different signatures.  `async` accepts a closure which accepts no parameters, but `dataTask` accepts a closure which accepts three parameters.  There's nothing "magic" about either of these functions; they simply accept closures, and you can write your own functions to accept closures if you like.

Comment: Thx. Good explanation and its clarified it for me. I was confusing the lecturer's words "returns no arguments". The dataTask takes a closure that "accepts" 3 arguments and i was confusing that for "returning" 3 arguments. Good that you copied the function signatures here cause that spelt it out clearly.

Comment: " trailing closure " is totally unnecessary syntax, it is unintuitive either.

Comment: @J-Q Sure, it's not *necessary*.  However, it's not difficult to understand, and it makes a lot of code much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Not all asynchronous APIs use multithreading.  Memory management has additional considerations when data is updated/transmitted between threads.    The lecturer's statements may have been made in the specific context of multithreaded APIs.  When your closure is processed in the same thread that issued the function call (or on the main thread), these considerations may not apply.